# Comments and feedback on rolling own dataframe functionality and syntax?

Tags: python, pandas, ternary

I want to roll my own dataframe functionality and syntax. Below is an example with a ternary-like operator:

**Example A**

Let's say I have a dataframe `df` and I want to set `row_A` equal to 5 if `row_B` is 10.

Right now, this has to be written like this:

```
df.loc[df.row_1 == ‘10’, 'row_1'] = 5
```

But I want this to work:

```
df.row_A = 5 if row_B = 10
```

My question is: is it feasible possible to add / overload the functionality implied? Has anyone tried this?

Example A above would just be the beginning.

While subjective, I think this deals with a large class of "not quite" esoteric operations, that are in fact arcane and esoteric to execute concisely in Pandas.

Note that I’m in principle happy to share / learn / complement / accept someone else's implementation too.

Comment: What about an else case?  In its current state, the desired solution will throw a syntax error.

Comment: This is a good point, it's not really the ternary operator. 

This is a sketch, the implication / desired functionality is that rows that do not satisfy this condition have their value unchanged (e.g. `df.row_A = 5 if row_B = 10 else row_a`).

The example is intended to illustrate.

Note that there's more than one problem with the example (it's using an assignment operator instead of `eq` or `==`.